# Sage wilting after transplanting

Tags: herbs, transplanting

After transplanting nine sage seedlings outside a week ago, all but one have wilted and almost died. They all looked healthy, about two inches tall. Strangely, the one that lives on is in the corner getting the least sun.

The thing I'm thinking is that I might be over watering? I did more reading today and noticed that sage doesn't like too much water.

Comment: Do you mean you transplanted 2 inch high seedlings into garden soil outdoors? Where had they been before you did  so, indoors; under cover; outside not in sun?

Comment: Yes. They had been on a windowsill indoors, so getting partial sun.

Answer (score 1):

If they were only 2 inches high, unless they had formed quite bushy little plants in individual little pots,they were effectively still seedlings, and not ready to take the rigours of being transferred outside, and especially not exposure to lots of direct sun. You don't say whether you hardened them off before planting outside, which they would have needed, and nor do you specify which particular sage variety they are, so it's  hard to comment on that.

Hopefully, the one that is left will survive and grow on.

Comment: I hardened it off for about a week before transplanting. How big should I have let them grow? This is my first year trying to grow my own plants, so I'll take any advice for future learning I can get. I used the seeds from a kit which unfortunately doesn't name the variety; and since these mostly wilted and died I have an order out for 'Salvia Officinalis' sage seeds.

Comment: The one left looks rather healthy and strong, btw. I find it fascinating how one can thrive when the others wilted away so quickly.

Comment: The others have keeled over because of too much sun - they weren't ready for it yet,that's why the one in the shadier spot is still okay. It may also be more sheltered from cold temperatures at night, because we've had a few hard frosts in the last few days. For seeds you need to start off inside or under cover, after they germinate and form little seedlings, they need pricking out  into little pots, then allowed to grow on before planting outdoors. Other  plant seeds can be sown direct in the ground.